# O comando "npm run build" não esta funcionado

Tags: react, build

O meu problema é o seguinte ao executar o comando (Para preparar os arquivos para produção):

```
npm run build
```

Ele não apresenta nenhum erro, aparentemente deu tudo certo:

```
c:\bin\node-v8.9.2-win-x64\teste_novo_projeto\my-app>npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build c:\bin\node-v8.9.2-win-x64\teste_novo_projeto\my-app
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  35.81 KB  build\static\js\main.ffeb9945.js
  420 B     build\static\css\main.8b8d5523.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build


c:\bin\node-v8.9.2-win-x64\teste_novo_projeto\my-app>
```

Apesar de não apresentar nenhum erro, ao executar a pagina, na tela apresenta tudo em branco, como se não tivesse nada na pagina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando executo o comando:

```
npm start
```

Ele funciona normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao da o build ela apresenta esta mensagem, que é vaga para mim:

> The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root. To
>   override this, specify the homepage in your package.json. For example,
>   add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

Eu tenho que da um "build" para cada host especifico que for utilizar? Por causa desta mensagem eu tentei executar a pagina em um servidor apache, mas continuou a pagina em branco.

Esta aplicação não consome nenhum webservice ela simplesmente converte a entrada base64 para uma string ou para imagem.

Existe algo que tenho que configurar como o "package.json" antes de da o "build"?

**Update**

Se eu editar o arquivo "index.html" o caminho

```
src="/static/js/main.ffeb9945.js"
```

para

```
src="static/js/main.ffeb9945.js"
```

Funciona, mas queria saber a forma correta de fazer esta alteração, antes mesmo de dar o build.

**Update**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "homepage": "http://localhost/react_build/",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**Update - Resposta da resposta do "Jan Cássio"**

O problema é que o caminho é inicializado com "/", com isso ele só vai funcionar se o projeto estiver na raiz do host, já fiz testes utilizando um servidor apache e também local nos dois casos o problema acontece, mas se eu for no build criado e editar manualmente o index.html e remover esta barra, funciona normalmente, isso soluciona o problema, mas eu queria fazer da forma correta, estou inicializando agora com react sei muito pouco, para não dizer nada, mas acredito que exista uma forma de configuração que ele 'compile'(build) funcionando, eu acredito piamente que estou fazendo algo de errado na hora do build, o que eu preciso é de criar um projeto e rodar em um servidor apache.

Comment: Aparentemente ele está avisando que as dependencia geradas pelo build depende de um rotas fixas, como `/css/styles.min.css`. No console ele mostra erros em carregamentos?

Comment: Sim, da erro de carregamento, coloquei no arquivo "package.json a linha "homepage" : "http://localhost/react_build", compilei mas continua com o mesmo endereço, como configuro este caminho? Obs: http://localhost/react_build é onde executei o projeto

Comment: O mais estranho é o seguinte se abro o fonte do index.html o caminho esta assim: src="/static/js/main.ffeb9945.js", teoricamente deveria funcionar

Comment: Se removo o src="/static/js/main.ffeb9945.js" por src="static/js/main.ffeb9945.js" funciona, mas queria saber a forma correta de fazer esta alteração.

Comment: Hmm, coloque as partes relevantes do seu `package.json` Wictor. Tente alterar de `localhost/react_build` para `localhost/react_build/`. Dica: após o deploy, ao inves de usar o apache, recomendo [http server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) do node.

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja somente com o apache mesmo. Ex: se tentar `localhost/react_build/static/js/main.ffeb9945.js` ele não vai devolver o script. Geralmente quando vou colocar em produção, opto pelo http node que comentei, que vai fazer isso acima e fica automatizado pra hospedar no Heroku ou bluemix..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70870/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-lucas-costa).

Comment: Esse é um dos grandes problemas do mundo node/package.json, quase todos projetos se baseiam em caminhos absolutos (já trabalhei com quase todos populares e todos tive esse problema), o que complica de resolver as coisas de forma simples, que deveria ser o essencial, um uso correto da tag `<base>` nesse frameworks populares resolveria, mas quem desenvolve esses sistemas quase sempre tem experiência em trabalhar muito, mas não tem entendimento real no básico (básico não é contrário de avançado, é a "base"), então acabam complicando.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque quando vc executa seu `index.html` com o prefixo `file://`, ele vai tentar carregar as dependencias relativas a este path e como não tem nenhuma aplicação em `http://` servindo esses assets, não vai achar mesmo.

Outra coisa, alguns browsers tem politica de segurança que impede execução de script em `file://`. Logo sua página provavelmente vai dar um *exception* e não vai funcionar também.

Sempre execute o projeto em uma aplicação que sirva ela em `http`, porque é a maneira correta e vc provavelmente não terá nenhum problema.

Se vc quiser ver seu projeto compilado na pasta `build` funcionando, vc pode rodar um *http server* apontando a raiz pra ela.

No mac ou linux, vc pode executar este comando dentro da pasta `build`:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Isso vai fazer subir um *http server* em `localhost:80`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá eu tive um problema parecido. No meu caso no package.json não tinha a chave `homepage` igual está no seu então eu adicionei porém um pouco diferente, só que fora da chave scripts.

Ficou assim:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  [...]
}
```

No meu resolveu, espero que te ajude.